# Any screen capture tool for Windows that can run from command line and has auto-scroll capability?

Tags: screen-capture

I'm looking for a screen capture tool for Windows (ideally supports `xp`, `vista` and `7`),
that **can execute command in command line and take screenshot** of, say, web page.
Then it should have **auto-scroll** feature so that I can scroll down the captured images.

I've tried `FastStone` capture and `DuckLink` and while they do have auto-scroll feature, it is not supported in command line (command line would just take screenshot without auto-scroll).

Comment: Just by looking at the side Related entries, I found http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/ which might be what you look for (at least for the Web).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've heard about IECapt too, maybe I might need to use different tool for different OS/browsers etc

Comment: I think I should move this to "SuperUser" instead here, just don't know how......

Comment: I agree, I actually voted for this move before commenting, but so far I am the only one, missing 4 other votes... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Autohotkey might help, building scripts to run i.e. faststone and select "capture webpage with scroll".